# Rule-based Conditional Formatting in R (openxlsx)

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, openxlsx

I'm trying to use the `conditionalFormatting()` function from the `openxlsx` package in R. I would like the function to compare date values in two columns (`A` and `B`), and color the cell value in `B` only if the value is smaller than `A`. Is this a stretch?

```r
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet1", cols=12, rows=1:nrow(data), rule = 'B<A', style = myStyle)
```

Comment: Hi, if my answer has solved your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rule = "$A2>$B2"`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = 1:6 + c(-1, 1))
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "sheet1")
writeData(wb, "sheet1", df)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "sheet1", cols = 2, rows = 2:(nrow(df)+1), rule = "$A2>$B2")
saveWorkbook(wb, "conditionalFormattingExample.xlsx", TRUE)
```

[image]

###### Reference

https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/reference/conditionalFormatting.html